# Qantas FF level change ahead of flight

Tags: loyalty-programs, qantas

I'm currently a silver level Qantas frequent flyer. I'm going to hit the gold level requirement after a longhaul flight with a stopover (Oz -> UK) and I'm wondering if there's any way to get Qantas to upgrade me before the flight takes place? I could really use the lounge access / early boarding on that trip.

I didn't find any information about people making such request on the internet, but I'd like to know if there's any better contact point than just calling up the usual membership enquiries phone numer.

Answer (score 9):

**No**, there's no way to make that happen officially.

You can always try your luck waving your boarding pass at the lounge, especially at the stopover lounge if your first flight has already taken you over the limit, but don't count on it.  The staff at the entrance are known as "lounge dragons" for a reason, and all boarding passes are scanned on entry, meaning there would likely be a record if they bend the rules in your favor.

If you've still got the lounge entry coupon you received when hitting Silver, now is the time to use it, or you can check out the likes of Flyertalk and see if anybody is willing to sell/barter you one.  There are also a bunch of credit cards that hand these out if you sign up.

Comment: So many lounges don't even check, in my experience.

Comment: @sevenseacat Check what?  In my experience lounges are usually *very* careful about who they let in!

Comment: Don't check? - hah! Where is this!